# Send message to skype group using Skype4com(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, skype4com

I'm creating a aplication in *.NET(C# - WinForms)* to send a automatic answer to my skype new messages, but I got a issue. My code that send de message is this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            skype = new Skype();

            skype.Attach(7, true);
            profileName.Text = skype.CurrentUser.FullName;
            temporizador.Start();
            picOffline.Visible = false;
            picOnline.Visible = false;


            temporizador.Start();
            picOffline.Visible = false;
            picOnline.Visible = false;

            //Monitor
            skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skypeId_MessageStatus);

        }
```

and the method that will answer is this:

```
public void skypeId_MessageStatus (IChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
        {
           if(status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                try
                {
                    skype.SendMessage(msg.FromHandle, resp);
                    //msg.Chat.SendMessage(resp);
                    msg.Seen = true;
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that the app isn't answering group chat, only a single contact new message. Using this library how can identify new group message and auto-reply they.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the line you commented out, which is

```
msg.Chat.SendMessage(resp);
```

This should work, as I just ran into this problem today.  You can also get rid of the line

```
skype.SendMessage(msg.FromHandle, resp);
```